# Вылезает текст за рамки фона

Tags: css

Добрый день. Подскажите, у меня фон (картинка) имеет ширину 100%, а высоту фиксированную. Если добавить слишком много текста (большого размера), то текст вылезет за рамки фона. Как это исправить?

```
.head {
    background-image: url(../images/Head.png);
    backgroung-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    height: 689px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: конечно будет вылазить у тебя же высота фиксированная

Comment: overflow:hidden

Comment: 'Как это исправить?' что получиться-то должно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А каким образом вы хотите это исправить?
Есть два способа: `overflow-y: hidden;` и `overflow-y: scroll;`
В первом случае текста видно не будет, во втором вылезающий за рамки текст будет не виден, но можно будет сделать прокрутку.